# My question is about the use of "lest" + "should have + past participle" in the sentence provided below

Tags: meaning, grammar

I have while reading Bram Stoker's 'Dracula' stumbled upon a sentence which has ever since been puzzling my mind and I have not been able to penetrate the grammar used. Here goes the sentence:

> "I do believe the dear soul thought I **might be** jealous, **lest** my poor
>   dear **should have fallen** in love with any other girl."

What exactly puzzles me are the following grammar structures: "lest" and "should have fallen". What meaning do they convey here? How do I understand them? I feel it's not commonly used grammar, and any help is very much appreciated. I have made bold all the structures I'm not quite sure of. 
I only know of the "should have + past participle" construction in a sense of regret, like "I should have studied harder." (while in fact I did not, hence the lamentation." But here the construction seems to be following some other frame of application.

Comment: Do understand that "lest" is archaic.  The quote you give appears to be idiomatic, given that.

Comment: I think I do understand this, but what word could "lest" be substituted to without losing its meaning in the context I'm not exactly sure of.

Comment: "lest" can often, including here, be replaced by "for fear that". We did not talk, lest we wake the baby.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: The conjunction _lest_ is not archaic, but not often used in unrehearsed speech.

Comment: I think the problem here is mostly with the auxillary *should*. From MW — used in auxiliary function to express condition — if he should leave his father, his father would die — Genesis 44:22 (Revised Standard Version). "I do believe the dear soul feared I might be jealous if my poor dear should have fallen in love with any other girl."

Comment: @PhilSweet Oh, this is of much help, many thanks! But, would the "if...should have fallen" clause have the same meaning to that of "if...had fallen"? Thanks again for the much desired clarification!

Comment: The *should* tells us that it didn't happen and keeps us located in the real present. Without it, we tend to be transported to the unreal and consider the hypothetical more closely. The *should* tells us to dismiss this failed eventuality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In case

"In case" is a common modern usage to convey this sense. Commonly this is coupled with "might"...

> I do believe the dear soul thought I might be jealous, in case my poor dear might have fallen in love with any other girl.

... or simply:

> I do believe the dear soul thought I might be jealous, in case my poor dear had fallen in love with any other girl.

Another example is:

> We did not open the suitcase, in case the moths might fly out.

or

> We did not open the suitcase, in case the moths flew out.

### Lest

This word is declining in use, according to Google's analysis of books:
[image]

Strictly speaking it should be combined with the subjunctive mood:

> We did not eat anything from the unsavoury roadside stall, lest we should fall ill.

However, there is a well known use of "lest" in a simple form of words, used in memorials in remembrance of soldiers who lost their lives in a war:

> "Lest we forget"

This comes from a Rudyard Kipling poem, Recessional, which begins:

```
God of our fathers, known of old,
Lord of our far-flung battle line,
Beneath whose awful hand we hold
Dominion over palm and pine—
Lord God of Hosts, be with us yet,
Lest we forget—lest we forget!
```

Comment: "...lest my poor dear should have fallen..." follows exactly the syntax of classical Latin, in which Bram Stoker, and many of his readers, would have been educated. Those words word therefore not strike them as antiquated because they would have been familiar with that form of expression since early schooldays.